# how to hide inner class element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here i need to hide the content inside tag .I need not want to hide the whole content class .how can i do that .this code is not working properly

```
<div class="content">
        <h2>hai</h2>
</div>

 document.getElementsByClassName("content.h2")[0].style.display="none";
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(".content h2").style.display="none"
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$(".content h2").hide();
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].firstChild.style.display = "none";
```

Although the second method is only going to work if you have the h2 as the first element inside your tag. Your best bet for vanilla javascript is probably going to be a `querySelector` method as has been posted by plenty of people.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```js
 document.querySelector(".content h2").style.display="none";
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <h2>hai</h2>
        <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` can only have a class name in parameters. You wrote "content.h2" which doesn't mean anything. What you want is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].style.display = "none";
```

You might also want to look at `querySelector` if you're aiming for a compatible browser.

```
document.querySelector(".content h2").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript implements a native method in "document" called "querySelector". You can use almost any html selector that you want.(like in css or jQuery)

So first we query for the class whit the "."

```
document.querySelector(".content");
```

That snnipet will return the dom of the parent div. Then you can select the inner H2 by extending the query.

```
document.querySelector(".content h2");
```

After that you can use the object has you want

```
document.querySelector(".content h2").style.display="none"
```

Or remove the object from the dom

```
document.querySelector(".content h2").remove();
```

Sorry for my english !

Answer (score -1):

Here you go 
try this

---

HTML

```
<div class="content">
        <h2 id="idname">hai</h2>
</div>
```

---

JS

```
document.getElementById('idname').innerHTML="";
```